# Testing Workflow when working on the Tensorflow source code

Tags: tensorflow

When developing with the tensorflow code base, it seems that the workflow is

1. Make code changes
2. Run bazel build
3. Build pip package
4. pip install pip package
5. Test changes

This is clunky. Are there any tricks for compiling and testing changes within the source tree? Something like setting one's `PYTHONPATH`

I'm aware that tensorflow doesn't allow importing from within the source tree. For e.g.

- [What does it mean to import TensorFlow from source directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150087/what-does-it-mean-to-import-tensorflow-from-source-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can run Tensorflow test cases using bazel, without installing anything, by running

```
bazel test //tensorflow/...
```

(or you can use a more precise path to run individual test cases.)

I would recommend you test your code by writing test cases and testing them with `bazel test`; no need to install anything.

If you want an interactive shell for ad hoc testing, I don't think there is currently a well-supported way to do that without building and installing the pip package. It sounds like a reasonable thing to want to do; I would open a GitHub issue if this is important to you.

Hope this helps!